# What 's difference for the latency between Storm and Spark Streaming when dealing with tuples\messages?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-storm

1,Based on the description below, Both Storm and Spark Streaming dealing with the messages/tuples in batch  or small/micro batch?
https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Trident-tutorial.html

2,If the answer for the above question is yes, it means both technologies have the delay when dealing with the  messages/tuples ? If that's the case why I heard often that latency for the Storm is better then Spark Streaming ,such as the below article?
https://www.ericsson.com/research-blog/data-knowledge/apache-storm-vs-spark-streaming/

3,From the Trident-tutorial it describes that :
"Generally the size of those small batches will be on the order of thousands or millions of tuples, depending on your incoming throughput."
So what's the really size of the small batch? thousands or millions of tuples?If it is , how Storm can keep the short latency?

https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Trident-tutorial.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storm's core api tries to process an event as it arrives. Its an event at a time processing model which can result in very low latencies.

Storm's Trident is a micro batching model built on top of the storm's core apis for providing exactly-once guarantees. Spark streaming is also based on micro batching and comparable to trident in terms of latencies.

So if one is looking for extremely low latency processing Storm's core api would be the way to go. However this guarantees only at-least once processing and theres a chance of receiving duplicate events in case of failures and the application is expected to handle this.

Take a look at the streaming benchmark from yahoo [1], that can provide more insights.

[1] https://yahooeng.tumblr.com/post/135321837876/benchmarking-streaming-computation-engines-at

Comment: Thank you for your clarification.